# Correct Back Fragment from Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation, fragmentmanager

I have a 3 fragments:
Activity Base -> Fragment A ->Fragment B -> Fragment C
Navigation is correct between these fragments but when I do:
Activity Base -> Fragment A ->Fragment B -> Fragment C -> Activity X

I can't get a correct navigation. When I press back on Activity X it goes to Fragment A (Activity Base) and doesn't go to Fragment C.

Any ideas? Thx

Comment: You need to save the fragment you are displaying before launching the new activity and load the fragment when you come back...  Take a look on the `startActivityForResult() ` method

Comment: are you replace fragments or add the fragments ?

Answer (score 0):

Activity Base should use `onSaveInstanceState` to store the current active fragment. Then it has to restore that fragment in either `onCreate` (if the `Bundle` parameter is not null), or in `onRestoreInstanceState`.

Note (from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29))

> Most implementations will simply use onCreate(Bundle) to restore their state, but it is sometimes convenient to do it [in onSaveInstanceState] after all of the initialization has been done or to allow subclasses to decide whether to use your default implementation